# How to forward part of input from one control to another without losing focus?

Tags: wpf, treeview, focus

Using WPF how can I do similar thing as done in Skype contacts window? I want to be able to press on any list item with mouse, be able to use Up/Down to navigate and filter contacts when I start typing. I also want to show what I'm typing in separated TextBox.

So far I have all filtering set up through TextBox. I can navigate with arrows when TreeView is focused and filter when entering text inside TextBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in the PreviewXXXX functions, which lets you catch key presses before they get to the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have skype, but I think you'll have to catch those up/down keys from the keyboard and send them to your treeview if I understand your question well.

... or perhaps [this link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/treeview/filtering-in-treeview.aspx) helps!